# flask_socket.io _ problem with running async tasks

Tags: python, flask-socketio, eventlet

I have this configuration on my flask project :

in requrement.txt:

```
flask_socketio
eventlet
```

in my app.py :

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="eventlet")


@socketio.on('register')
async def register(data):

    await my_asyncfunction(data['machine_id'])
```

and my_asyncfunction:

```
async def my_asyncfunction(data):
   ....
```

and this is my error:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py:870: RuntimeWarning: coroutine
> 'my_asyncfunction' was never awaited  self._target(*self._args,
> **self._kwargs)RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

so I tried the option `async_mode="eventlet"` but same error :(

Answer (score 2):

Neither Flask, Flask-SocketIO nor eventlet support asyncio, you cannot mix regular and async functions in this way.

If your application uses asyncio functions, then you have to drop Flask, Flask-SocketIO and eventlet, and instead use [python-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio), which does support asyncio.

Comment: tnx for reply . so the scenario here is. I have flask for HTTP request and  socket-io flask for handling tiny microservice workers. which workers connect to my backend. after connection established between worker and server . worker sends the machine-id(mac address) for registration in the cloud(pods in Kubernetes). so this registration have to awaited and response needs to emit to that worker. so how should I handle this problems?

Comment: See the Flask-SocketIO documentation for examples of how to use Socket.IO with Flask. As I said in my answer, you cannot use asyncio in a Flask application.